# SQL select distinct data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I'm quite new in SQL, and can not find answer to my question. I have only one big table, and need to extract a two distinct columns from it with extra data from some other columns.

**Example:**

**table1**

```
id  animal  color   size     name, breed etc
1   cat     white   medium
2   cat     white   big
3   dog     white   medium
5   dog     white   big
6   cat     black   small
7   cat     black   small
```

I ask "select distinct..." for an animal and color and two more columns with id and size. So I need answer like this:

**Result:**

```
1  cat  white  medium
3  dog  white  medium
6  cat  black  small
```

I've tried to join table, but did not succeed.

Comment: Target is MySQL 5.5. But query should be simple and universal 'cos of Possible changes

Comment: What is the criteria for choosing the two more column for example size? should be maximum size or minimum size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you described, something like this might do the job:

```
SQL> with test (id, animal, color, c_size) as
  2  (select 1, 'cat', 'white', 'medium' from dual union
  3   select 2, 'cat', 'white', 'big'    from dual union
  4   select 3, 'dog', 'white', 'medium' from dual union
  5   select 5, 'dog', 'white', 'big'    from dual union
  6   select 6, 'cat', 'black', 'small'  from dual union
  7   select 7, 'cat', 'black', 'small'  from dual
  8  )
  9  select min(id) id, animal, color, max(c_size) c_size
 10  from test
 11  group by animal, color;

        ID ANI COLOR C_SIZE
---------- --- ----- ------
         1 cat white medium
         3 dog white medium
         6 cat black small

SQL>
```

Comment: @Littlefoot why did you use min for id and max for size?

Comment: Because that's what OP's "Results" suggest, @sia. From my point of view, could have been either MAX or MIN in both cases, it is just that the result has to show distinct animal, its color and *any* size it might have so - I picked MAX. As of ID, I took the first appearance for [animal + color] combination (and "first" means "MIN" in this context).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using over() partition clause.

select animal, colour, size from 
  (
       Select animal, colour, size, row_number() over (partition  by animal, colour order by size) as rowx
         from table_name
) 
as X  where rowx = 1;

Comment: Would you please add formatting to the answer, so your code part would be easier to read.